# Deeplink issue after upgrading gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-deep-link

I have app using deeplinks with navigation component. Until usage of AGP 8.0.2 and gradle wrapper 8.0 everything was working perfect.
I have verified that just this update causes collapse of recognizing my deeplinks in system causing error "Activity not started, unable to resolve intent"

My config of deeplinks is following:

```html
//MAnifest
<activity
            android:name=".delivery.DeliveryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/delivery_nav_graph" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="myschemea://"
                    android:host="myhost.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/receipt/delivery" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
/**
* Graph
*/

 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/delivery_payment_result"
        android:name="mypackage.delivery.payment.DeliveryPaymentResultFragment"
        android:label="@string/payment_result_title">

        <deepLink
            android:autoVerify="false"
            app:mimeType="type/subtype"
            app:uri="myschema://myhost/receipt/delivery" />
     
    </fragment>
```

I have no rights (WTF) to post it on google issue tracker so writing here. Maybe somebody has some idea what is going on?
As said - compared current version app and same but with reversed gradle updates and result is crystal clear

EDIT:
I had run some more checks and seems that solely updating AGP is causing trouble. They had released now 8.1.1 and issue stays same.

Comment: "I have no rights (WTF) to post it on google issue tracker" - note that if you are trying to put something in a subcategory of the `Android Studio` component, that is indeed not allowed. Their process is to triage all bugs added directly to the `Android Studio` component - they'll move it into the proper subcomponent for you.

Comment: Where would one post this? Is there an ongoing issue being tracked from this? @
ianhanniballake ?

Comment: @MarcoRS there is no much to track. My issue has been forgotted by google team and I marked at as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found issue.
Seems that in previous tools versions schema like:
"mySchema://" or "HTTP://" was accepted on 8.1.* gradle tools is no longer and it should be without leading :// like:
"mySchema" or "HTTP"

Comment: So how does one go about fixing a deep link from an external SDK that generates referral deep links? Our team is for example experiencing broken links using the latest AppsFlyer SDK (6.12.4).

Comment: You just have to report issue to owner of sdk. There is no other way. Seems that Google has changed way of handling this wihtout any information